# Is there an ESLint rule that checks the number of logical operators in a conditional expression?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am looking for such a rule to see the complexity of the conditional expression.

For example, if the threshold is 5, the following conditional expression would result in an error:

```js
if ((true && false) || ((false || true) && (true || false))) {
  // ...
}
```

However, the following conditional expression will not produce an error:

```js
if ((true && false) || ((false || true) && true)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: How about `const cond = (true && false) || ((false || true) && (true || false)); if (cond) {/*...*/}`? Should it be permitted?

Comment: I had not considered that case, but I think it should be allowed since the rule is only looking within the conditional expression.

Comment: So, the rule would be “4 or fewer total combined instances of the following operators (`&&`, `||`) within an `if` statement’s conditional expression”?

Comment: Yes, it would. But, I also think the rule should see the contents of `cond`. However, in that case, I feel that it would be better to do it at the time of assignment to `cond` instead of counting the logical operators in `cond` in the if statement.

Comment: Ok, so use [the previous description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73060791/is-there-an-eslint-rule-that-checks-the-number-of-logical-operators-in-a-conditi?noredirect=1#comment129039225_73060791) except change the last criterion to: "...within any expression"?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see such a rule.

Comment: [Creating an ESLint plugin](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/working-with-plugins) is the way you'd go about creating a new custom rule. Or someone might have already created a community plugin that lets you provide an AST callback function and other info in the config (which would be even easier to use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [an ESLint plugin to check the number of logical operator](https://github.com/tomyam2020/eslint-plugin-complex-logic).
For the moment, it only check the number of logical operators in the conditional expression of the if statement. But I may update the rule to get to check any expression.